# One of my imports is not working

Tags: netbeans, javafx

I am trying to copy a code from a java game development book using javafx, it uses netbeans, but i am using eclipse with a e(fx)clipse.
 The "import.javafx.scene.control.Button:" 
Shows a red line stating " the import collides with another import statement.

Comment: Should not be a "." after import.

Comment: Right sorry, that was a typo, my original code doesnt have s "." After import

Comment: First you should make sure you didn't import a Swing Button. Also, if you are using Netbeans you can delete the import and you will get an error light bulb in the code. You can then click on it to add the correct import back.

Comment: You can still [edit] the question, if it contains a typo.